# Symfony2 : site stop working afer clear:cache

Tags: php, symfony, caching

I'm updating a symfony2 website, afeter each update in controller or twig file I run "php app/console cache:clear", the website stop working for 5 minutes then it works again. After un very little update, I cleared the cache and the site don't want to run anymore, I have 500 Internal Server Error, there are no entry in symfony's log file, but here what I found in php log :

```
[Thu Sep 24 08:10:05 2015] [error] [client 1.2.3.4] FastCGI: server "/run/fcgi-bin/www.mysite.com:80.fcgi" stderr: PHP message: PHP Warning:  require_once(/var/www/mysite.com/app/cache/prod/jms_diextra/doctrine/EntityManager_5602df03afff5.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/mysite.com/app/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainer.php on line 279

[Thu Sep 24 08:10:05 2015] [error] [client 1.2.3.4] FastCGI: server "/run/fcgi-bin/www.mysite.com:80.fcgi" stderr: PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/mysite.com/app/cache/prod/jms_diextra/doctrine/EntityManager_5602df03afff5.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/mysite.com/app/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainer.php on line 279
```

It seems to be entity issue, but I'm sure I have no entity updates. I even tried to roll back by uploading all original files but no way !

I don't understand :

1. why do I have to wait 5 minutes after each cache:clear ?
2. what does the log errors means ?

Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I followed the instructions in URL posted by tchap.
I don't know why `cache:clear` throws the bug, but I tested this and it works :

1. manually delele the `/app/cache/prod/` folder
2. run :

   ```
   app/console cache:warmup
   ```

Comment: In my case the cache folder path was on var/cache/prod/

Answer (score 6):

It looks like a file permission problem on your `cache` directory (and/or your `logs` directory).

Try `chmod -R 777 app/cache app/logs` and tell us if you still have problems.

You can also check the **umask** trick in http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#checking-symfony-application-configuration-and-setup that may help in your case.

Comment: Better: Make sure that the php process on your server has write rights on the cache folder (and logs for that matter). 777 is ok to debug in this case though

Comment: Yes, that's right. 777 is for your local install. Proper right and user permissions should be enforced in a production instance

Comment: The 'problem' is the site is now working without any action, so I can't try your solution! But when it was down I tried "chmod -R 777 app/cache" but it didn't work. And I wonder : if it's a right problem, why the early cache:clear worked fine ?

Comment: Maybe also linked to this : https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSDiExtraBundle/issues/23 ?

Comment: chmod -R 777 app/cache app/logs did not solved the problem !

Comment: You can try `sudo find app/cache -type f -delete` as well, it's a bit more aggressive when you want to delete old cache files